# Can you explain the interest line: Shopify vs. Magento on Google Trends?

Tags: locations

If we check Google Trends and compare "Shopify" and "Magento" terms by filtering only "United States", we will see that interest live for Shopify will overpower Magento very soon. What do you think are the main reasons?

Thank you!

[image: Shopify vs. Magento Interest Line on Google Trends]

Comment: The discussion will be closed off but - whoever compares these two has no idea what they are doing. Shopify is a SaaS platform for Nano Enterprise (sub $200k revenue) - Magento CE is $200K to $3mil - yes you can use either above and below the target market but various dynamics come in to play. The main reason - eBay has no idea what they are doing with Magento - so lack of trust arises and people look for least worst - that's the SaaS providers. All very simple.

Comment: Yep, basically Magento is user unfriendly for the small shops who've decided to move on after finding out they need to be programmers, DB and web server admins. Lots of small business plans out there that thought they were getting something for free, the rest of us realized we were getting an e-commerce web kit which when combined with a really good service provider, could give us some advantages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily opinion based and it appears to be misdirecting question